# How can I change 8 digit number's last digit with just using primitive data types?

Tags: java, binary

This is the question.
An alien spaceship broadcasts a frequency of digital signals that can be
converted into 0-1 digits (always a 8 digit combination). In brief, a stream of digits entered via the console is supposed to be caught. It is obvious that the digits we acquire can be converted into base ten - decimal. The situation here is the noise which interferes with the original signal that we are listening to. Signal noise, which negates the last item of the stream, may appear in the very first character of your input stream. All of the characters must be either 0 or 1, otherwise it is a noise. Every first character is always 0. The input stream will be taken as a single set of numeric characters.

I changed too many thing in code and still it is not working with all numbers. But I got the message from these codes:
01000110
21010011
21001000
01000101
01001110
51000101
when we converted these to correct version it'll give the message. For example these give "FRIEND". I found this but program is not working with 00000000. It gives error. How can I correct this.

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int frequency = inp.nextInt();
        int digit1 = frequency/10000000;
        int digit2 = (frequency/1000000)%10;
        int digit3 = (frequency/100000)%10;
        int digit4 = (frequency/10000)%10;
        int digit5 = (frequency/1000)%10;
        int digit6 = (frequency/100)%10;
        int digit7 = (frequency/10)%10;
        int digit8 = frequency%10;
        
        int decimal_version = digit1*10000000 + digit2*1000000 + digit3*100000 + digit4*10000 + digit5*1000 + digit6*100 + digit7*10 + digit8;
        
        System.out.println(decimal_version);
```

Comment: What is the error? Please [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Change the last bit of 8-digit number:
`num ^= 1B`

Comment: I couldn't understand what you meant.